# Continuously checking database from a Windows service

Tags: sql, windows-services

I am making a Windows service which needs to continuously check for database entries that can be added at any time to tell it to execute some code.  It is looking to see if it's status is set to pending, and it's execute time entry is > than the current time.  Is the only way to do this to just run select statements over and over?  It might need to execute the code every minute which means I need to run the select statement every minute looking for entries in the database.  I'm trying to avoid unneccesary cpu time because I'm probably going to end up paying for cpu cycles on the hosting provider

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be aware that Notification Services is only for SQL 2005, and has been dropped from SQL 2008.

Rather than polling the database for changes, I would recommend writing a CLR stored procedure that is called from a trigger, which is raised when an appropriate change occurs (e.g. insert or update). The CLR sproc alerts your service which then performs its work.

Sending the service alert via a TCP/IP or HTTP channel is a good choice since you can deploy your service anywhere, just by modifying some configuration parameter that is read by the sproc. It also makes it easy to test the service.

I would use an event driven model in your service. The service waits on an auto-reset event, starting a block of work when the event is raised. The sproc communications channel runs on another thread and sets the event on each incoming request.

Assuming the service is doing a block of work and a set of multiple pending requests are outstanding, this design ensures that those requests trigger just 1 more block of work when the current one is finished.

You can also have multiple workers waiting on the same event if overlapping processing is desired.

*Note:* for external network access the `CREATE ASSEMBLY` statement will require the `PERMISSION_SET` option to be set to `EXTERNAL_ACCESS`.

Comment: I think this would not be nearly as robust as just having the Windows Service poll the database with some SELECT statement. What happens if that trigger fires when the Windows Service is down? With polling, when the Win Service comes back up, it would "catch up" and perform all of the transactions it missed while it was down. Windows Services can be down for many reasons like rebooting the server after updates. Perhaps the Windows Server is a VM in a VM Cluster and misses the request while being migrated from one host to another. I am going with polling.

Comment: I envisaged that the notification from the trigger is just "something happened", not "here are the details". The service would still have to request the pending work details when notified and on startup, but my model avoids unnecessary network traffic and minimizes lag between the event and the data request.

Answer (score 1):

Given you talk about the service provider, I suspect one of the main alternatives will not be open to you, which is notification services. It allows you to register for data changed events and be notified, without the need to poll the database. It does however require service broker enabled for it to work, and that potentially could be a problem if it is hosted - some companies keep it switched off.

The question is not tagged to a specific database just SQL, the notification services is a SQL Server facility.

Comment: It might be easier to find a provider that allows notification servers than get a provider where I need a vm which can host a windows service.  I haven't chosen a provider yet

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server and open to a different approach, check out [SQL Server Notification Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166495(SQL.90).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Oracle also provides notifications, the call it [Database Change Notification](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_dcn.htm)